# MVC RadioButtonFor Confusion

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I was watching a tutorial video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=04RY04uKq2s , and I'm just not understanding what's happening with RadioButtonFor.

Basically, the guy creates a Company class:

```
public class Company
{

    public string SelectedDepartment {get; set;}


    public List<Department> Departments
    {
        get
        {
            SampleDBContext db = new SampleDBContext();
            return db.Departments.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

`

Ok, pretty straight-forward. He uses EntityFramework here, which has generated the SampleDBContext class.

Then he has a very simple Index ActionMethod:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Company company = new Company();
    return View();
}
```

A strongly-typed View for this [HttpGet]:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
foreach (var department in Model.Departments)
{
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedDepartment, department.Id, (department.IsSelected.HasValue && department.IsSelected.Value) ? new (@checked = "checked")} : null
    @department.Name
}

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />[Resulting View][1]
```

And finally this HttpPost ActionMethod:

```
[HttpPost]
public string Index(Company company)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(company.SelectedDepartment)
    {
        return "You selected nothing";
    }
    else
    {
        return "You selected department id: " + company.SelectedDepartment;
    }
```

Ok, whew. The database has 3 columns, Id, Name and IsSelected (a bit type).

So, 
    1..HR..1
    2..Payroll..NULL
    3..IT..NULL

Long post? I hope not. Every piece is very straight-forward.

Now for my questions:

(1)How does RadioButtonFor() use (m=>m.SelectedDepartment)? As in, why does the [HttpPost] method check to see if it's string is null or empty?

(2)When you print out the value of company.SelectedDepartment in the method, you get the ID. Where does this assignment take place?

Comment: Most of this code is nonsense or bad practice, including having database access in the class, initializing a new object in the GET method but then not returning it to the view, and adding the last parameter in the `RadioButtonFor()` for method (its the value of `SelectedDepartment` which determines what is selected and it should be just `@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedDepartment, department.Id)`).

Comment: The 1st parameter is the property you bind to (`SelectedDepartment`) and the 2nd parameter is the `value` (in this case `department.Id`) so when you select say the 2nd radio button which has a value of say `5`, then `5` is bound to `SelectedDepartment` when you submit

Comment: @StephenMuecke I realize this isn't best practice. These tutorials are really just demonstrative. Obviously a multi-tiered approach is better.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes, this is clearing up now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view code there is missing definition of the actual model the view works with. You can do that by adding `@model CompanyNamespace.Company`.

1. `m => m.SelectedDepartment` is a lambda that selects property of the Model which you can check in your Post action to retrieve `value` of a radio button the user has selected. In case user didn't select any radio button, that value is `null` (or in general `default(T)`, in this case `default(string)` = `null`), thus the if condition in the Post action.
2. Second argument of `RadioButtonFor` specifies what value will each radio button have. Since in your case it is `department.Id`, the value of each generated radio button  is Id of a department.

As for the code, as someone else already pointed out in the comment to your answer, I wouldn't really recommend you to use the aproach you posted and probably switch to some other source for learning MVC. IIRC, there are same easy-to-follow tutorials on [asp.net](http://www.asp.net/mvc).

**Edit:**
When you submit the form, the request is routed to the action decorated with `[HttpPost]`, and model binder binds posted data to the argument (or arguments) of your method by trying to match either argument names or properties of complex object to Post data. So when user selected some radio button it's value (which is taken from `department.Id` as specified by RadioButtonFor call) is assigned to `company.SelectedDepartment` property.

*The edit that expands on model binding was inspired by @Jaquez [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38907684/4955259) in an attempt to provide a more complete description and when I later compared the two (after this was selected as the answer by OP), it seemed to me, that it ended up - to a large extent - as an restatement of that part of @Jaquez answer. I consider it fair to mention this.*

Comment: Yes, there was something just not clicking with me on this. I simply neglected that the POST method was capturing m => m.SelectedDepartment. That property is not in the class for Department, which made things less clear.

Comment: I would also recommend you to take a look at the actual generated HTML in your browser and perhaps play with the view code a little bit to see how it changes - that way you can get quite a good idea of what exactly does `RadioButtonFor` (and other HtmlHelper methods) do.

Comment: I did check out the HTML but it didn't quite help in this case as each name/value had identical strings set. These @Html..For Helpers are quite confusing at first glance. The lambda expressions really don't seem to make things easier. I had to dig quite a bit to get the gist of anonymous methods, delegates, the implicit data types, etc. Could they not have simplified this syntax?

Comment: I actually quite like the syntax for HtmlHelper methods. Though I definitelly understand that if you haven't used lambdas in C# too much before, it can look quite confusing at first. In ASP.NET Core MVC (aka MVC 6) the syntax for [forms](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/views/working-with-forms.html) has changed a lot and the resulting View markup is closer to the actual generated HTML and I think that you will probably like it much more. And if you're just starting with MVC, then why not start with the currently newest version? ASP.NET Core MVC is in stable release version.

Comment: Great answer.  I overlooked a few details in mine and this was much more thorough.

Comment: Thanks, @Jaquez. It was actually your answer that inspired me to expand on how the model binding works via edit, so kudos to you too.

Comment: @davke I love multiple sources to understand the concepts. I haven't had any trouble except with lambda expressions. There is so much documentation out there for MVC but not so much for Core MVC.

Answer (score 3):

The code you have shared does not follow common conventions, and really does not make much sense at all.

Here is what a more conventional approach to the sample problem would look like:

### Company Model

```
public class Company
{
    public int CompanyId {get; set;}
    public string SelectedDepartment {get; set;}
    public List<Department> DepartmentsList {get; set;}
}
```

### Department Model

```
public class Department
{
    public int DepartmentId {get; set;}
    public string DepartmentName {get; set;}
}
```

### View

```
@model CompanyNamespace.Company

@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CompanyId)

    foreach (Department department in Model.DepartmentsList)
    {
        @Html.LabelFor(model => modelItem.department)
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => modelItem.SelectedDepartment, department.DepartmentName)
    }

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

### Controller

```
SampleDBContext db = new SampleDBContext();

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Company company = new Company();

    company.SelectedDepartment = null;
    company.DepartmentList = db.Departments.ToList();

    return View("Index", company);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Company company)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    db.Companies.Add(company);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index")
}
```

### Database Sample

```
+-----------+
| Companies |
+-----------+
+-----------------+--------------------------------+
| CompanyId (Int) | SelectedDepartment (VarChar20) |
+-----------------+--------------------------------+
| 1               | Clothing Department            |
| 2               | Electronics Department         |
| 3               | Furniture Department           |
+-----------------+--------------------------------+

+-------------+
| Departments |
+-------------+
+--------------------+----------------------------+
| DepartmentId (Int) | DepartmentName (VarChar20) |
+--------------------+----------------------------+
| 1                  | Clothing Department        |
| 2                  | Electronics Department     |
| 3                  | Furniture Department       |
| 4                  | Hardware Department        |
+--------------------+----------------------------+
```

### To answer your questions...

"model => modelItem.SelectedDepartment" is a lamda expression. The expression says "This radio button will represent the SelectedDepartment field of the model".

Since all the radio buttons in the view represent the same SelectedDepartment field in the mode, only one radio button will be able to be selected at once.

The value of the selected radio button, which is "department.DepartmentName" in our case, will be the value sent back to the model (and to the database).

Please note that the http post method in our control no longer returns a string. In order to see the changes to your data, you will have to look directly in your database.

Answer (score 1):

The null or empty string check is required because the values of radio buttons are only included in the POST if a button is selected.  This is the same for check boxes as well and is part of the web standards themselves, not MVC.

The value for company.SelectDepartment is assigned when the MVC framework takes the submitted value and uses it to instantiate a new instance of the type of the (POST) Index method's parameter. This is done by matching property names from the submitted data to the property names of the parameter's type.  By using the RadioButtonFor helper method with a typed model, you guarantee that the name of the radio buttons and the names of submitted values match the type required by the Index method.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why this blew my mind so much. A little bit of this View syntax is really ugly code. Essentially 3 'languages' in one View? I don't know if I'm a fan of that.

Comment: Indeed, it can be a bit confusing.  As @davke mentioned above, it does get better with ASP.NET Core MVC.